# How do you call object's methods from within a promise .then()?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a js object, and I have a method that calls another method and gets returned a promise, but from within .then() I cannot access a member function foo(). Why can't I access foo() and how can I access it? Here is my code:

```js
function LoadImageGroupFormat() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open('GET', "imagegroup_format.txt");
      xhttp.onload = function() {
        if (xhttp.status == 200) resolve(xhttp.responseText);
        else reject(Error(xhttp.statusText));
      };
      xhttp.onerror = function() {
        reject(Error("Network Error"));
      };
      xhttp.send();
    });
  }
  //the object
var Registerhandler = {
  imageGroupIndex: 0,

  foo: function() {
    //Do something else here
  },

  GetImageGroupFormat: function() {
    var imageGroupIndex = this.imageGroupIndex;
    LoadImageGroupFormat().then(function(ImageGroup_Format) {
      //Do something with ImageGroup_Format
      imageGroupIndex++; //This works
      foo(); //Doesn't work - undefined
    }, function(error) {
      console.error("Failed to Load ImageGroup Format", error);
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: `imageGroupIndex++;` "works" because you made a local variable `imageGroupIndex`, it isnt modifying `Registerhandler.imageGroupIndex`

Comment: How would I modify the instance's variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` is a property, not a function/variable name, you need to call it using property syntax. And since `this` isn't saved in closures, you need to define a local closure variable to hold it.

You also need to use `self.imageGroupIndex` to update that property, otherwise you're incrementing a copy of the value.

```
var Registerhandler = {
  imageGroupIndex: 0,

  foo: function() {
    //Do something else here
  },

  GetImageGroupFormat: function() {
    var self = this;
    LoadImageGroupFormat().then(function(ImageGroup_Format) {
      //Do something with ImageGroup_Format
      self.imageGroupIndex++;
      self.foo();
    }, function(error) {
      console.error("Failed to Load ImageGroup Format", error);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), *The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its **`this`** keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.*

```js
function LoadImageGroupFormat() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('success!'); //updated fro demonstration purpose
  });
}
var Registerhandler = {
  imageGroupIndex: 0,
  foo: function() {
    alert('In foo!');
  },

  GetImageGroupFormat: function() {
    var imageGroupIndex = this.imageGroupIndex;
    LoadImageGroupFormat().then(function(ImageGroup_Format) {
      console.log(ImageGroup_Format);
      this.imageGroupIndex++;
      this.foo();
    }.bind(this), function(error) {
      console.error("Failed to Load ImageGroup Format", error);
    });
  }
}
Registerhandler.GetImageGroupFormat();
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. At the time you call `.bind`, you're not in a method of the object, so `this` is not set to the object.

Comment: @Barmar, I have provided a demo..Let me know it it fails..

Comment: @Barmar Yes you are. `bind` is directly called in the `GetImageGroupFormat` method.

Comment: Sorry, I misread, I thought you were calling `.bind()` on the `GetImageGroupFormat` function, not the `.then()` function inside it.

Comment: @Barmar, In my initial answer, I did that way only.. Thanks for correction :)